# How can I decode the block of hyperledger fabric?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I built up a network via the test-network.sh in the fabric-samples.
I use the command

```
docker cp a4c:/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/mychannel/blockfile_000000 .
```

to copy the block in peer to my host Linux system. The `a4c` is the container id of `peer0.org1.com`.
I want to convert it to a `.json` file.
But there are some problems.

My hyperledger fabric version is `2.3.0`.
My configtxgen version is

```
configtxgen:
 Version: 2.3.0
 Commit SHA: ec81f3e74
 Go version: go1.14.12
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

My configtxlator version is

```
configtxlator:
 Version: 2.3.0
 Commit SHA: ec81f3e74
 Go version: go1.14.12
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

When I use the command

```
configtxgen -inspectBlock blockfile_000000 >> blockfile.json
```

It returns

```
2023-02-21 16:38:22.631 CST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2023-02-21 16:38:22.631 CST [common.tools.configtxgen] doInspectBlock -> INFO 002 Inspecting block
2023-02-21 16:38:22.631 CST [common.tools.configtxgen] doInspectBlock -> INFO 003 Parsing genesis block
2023-02-21 16:38:22.631 CST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> FATA 004 Error on inspectBlock: error unmarshaling to block: error unmarshaling Block: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 7
```

When I use the command

```
configtxlator proto_decode --type common.Block --input blockfile_000000 --output blockfile.json
```

It returns

```
configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error unmarshaling: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 7
```

However, I can decode the `genesis.Block` and `mychannel.Block` in line with my expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the specific problem is here, but I would suggest using versions of Fabric binaries that exactly match the version of Fabric that you are using. As per the [Fabric install instructions](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), you can download binaries for a specific version, something like this:

```bash
curl --location https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/install-fabric.sh | bash -s -- --fabric-version 2.2.10 binary
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I mixed my fabric version. Actually, I uses fabric v2.3.0 and my binaries are compiled at the same time with my fabric samples. I have correct it in my question. Does the go version influence the decode process? I notice that the binaries `configtxgen` and `configtxlator` are complied by go1.14.12 but in my vritual machine there is go1.15.13 installed.

Comment: I have found the approach to extract a block content. I need to use ```peer channel fetch -c mychannel <block id> <local filename>``` to fetch the specific block and then use the tool  `configtxlator` to extract the content of the target block.

Comment: Glad you got it working! The Go version in your environment should not affect the binaries.